# How to set a website as Wallpaper in Gnome

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I've been searching for about an hour right now. I can't seem to figure a way to set a website as the desktop background.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To change the Ubuntu desktop background, you can right-click the desktop and select "Change Desktop Background." To add a picture taken from the internet:

```
Change the search location drop-down menu from Wallpapers to Pictures Folder.
Click the plus sign to add a folder.
Browse to the desired picture.
```

Another way to get there would be clicking on the Dash Home (like Windows start menu) and typing "System." Desktop background settings are under Appearance.

As for using images from the internet, you need to download/save them locally.  An easy way to do this is to find one you like from a site like this: http://www.ubuntuwallpapers.com/.  If you view the image in its own window, for a full view, then it will be cleaner when you use it.  Next right-click on the image and select Save Image as.  I recommend saving to your pictures folder.

Comment: there is no option to put in a website there, just a picture/image

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to enter in a websites' URL to set your wallpaper.  I've edited my answer to include how you can though.

Comment: In the duplicate it gives a very good answer. Ubuntu is a desktop distro, this question should be for a distribution not meant for desktops. I would delete the question, but I think it works fine as a catch for the other question. Should I delete this Q b/c the other one gives the answer.